# NoMethodError: undefined method `position' for #<Faq:0x00000108195e70>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a bunch of FAQ's and I've added the gem ["Act As List"](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) to alter the position of the Faq's moving the Q&A up or down. However, everytime I run  rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
== 20140801122511 CreateFaqs: migrating =======================================
-- create_table(:faqs)
   -> 0.0997s
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `position' for #<Faq:0x00000108195e70>/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activemodel-4.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:167:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.4.0/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:448:in `check_top_position'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__2595859388242035249__validation__callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activemodel-4.0.4/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_validations!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activemodel-4.0.4/lib/active_model/validations.rb:314:in `valid?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in `valid?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `block in create!'
```

**Faq.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: faqs
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  question   :string(255)
#  answer     :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  position   :integer
#

class Faq < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list
  default_scope order('position')
end
```

**faqs_controller.rb**

```
class FaqsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @banner = Banner.active.first
    @faqs = Faq.all
  end
end
```

Any idea what's going wrong here? Thanks!

**Update (migrated in this order):**

**create_faws migration:**

```
class CreateFaqs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :faqs do |t|
      t.string :question
      t.text :answer

      t.timestamps
    end


end
```

**add_position_to_faqs migration:**

```
class AddPositionToFaqs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :faqs, :position, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show your migration file.

Comment: What version is your schema file running before you try to migrate?

Comment: @ABMagil good call - I have no idea, how can I check?

Comment: Looks like the schema.rb version though is: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140914201232) do

Comment: acts_as_list is kicking in when you are running your create_table migration where you do not define the position column (and hence the attribute). If you are at the very beginning add those columns to the create_table migration itself instead of having two migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding this as an answer for the sake of completeness)

acts_as_list is kicking in when you are running your create_table migration where you do not define the position column (and hence the attribute). If you are at the very beginning add those columns to the create_table migration itself instead of having two migrations.

Comment: I would have one more question - why is it loading `Faq` model at all? Normally migrations loads the whole environments, but models are not loaded until needed.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but it could be because eager loading is on. If we could see the stack trace further down we might get a hint. Also I do not know anything about the "Act as List" gem. So do not know what it is doing to be activated during a migration.